# Template pointer initialisation

Tags: c++

I have a template class

```
template <class T>
class MyTemplate
{
public:
    struct node
    {
        int a;
    };
    MyClass();
    ~MyClass();
private:
    static node* theNode;
};

template <class T>
MyClass::node* MyClass<T>::theNode = 0;
```

But the initialization of `theNode` fails -
use of class template requires template argument list
If I change the declaration to

```
MyClass<T>node* MyClass<T>::theNode = 0;
```

I get

> error C2143: syntax error : missing ';' before '*'

Please can someone tell me what the correct syntax is?

Comment: is `MyTemplate` supposed to say `MyClass` ?

Comment: typos everywhere ... Fix it then do Use: `typename MyTemplate<T>::node* MyTemplate<T>::theNode = 0;`

Answer (score 6):

Just change your definition:

```
template<class T>
typename MyClass<T>::node* MyClass<T>::theNode = 0;
```

Comment: Is my answer anachronistic?

Comment: That's a shame. There's nothing wrong with downvoting terrible answers. It's what the mechanism is for. (I've upvoted this.)